# What changes affect the updated time on a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, feeds

I'm working with a YouTube feed and showing a set of videos in date order. Currently, I'm basing that on the `updated` field - that seemed appropriate at the time. However, I'm now seeing the same videos getting updated again and again, seemingly when no-one has made any changes to them.

Does anyone know what kind of changes affect the `updated` date in YouTube data feeds?

Comment: Why not base it on the **published** field?

Comment: @Simon: I'm looking into that alternative now, but I'm still curious :) (also, if the video itself is changed, that would probably be relevant)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's actually possible to change the video itself. I'm pretty sure if you want to modify the video itself in any way, you need to upload a new video. So the 'updated' probably applies to things like description, tags, subtitles, captions, etc.

Comment: Ah - good point on the changing of a video. That sounds familiar! It's very strange because, in this particular case, no-one's owning up to editing *anything* related to the video (there are no comments, for a start) so it looks as if it would be wise just to stay away from 'updated' altogether.